# Django: How to get parent url when iframe is loaded

Tags: django, python-3.x, iframe, x-frame-options

I am using `@xframe_options_exempt` in my django view so that I can load this view from an iframe.

I want to do some `if url = xxx` filtering on the page but I need to get the Parent URL of the iframe.

For example the parent url is "http://mycoolsite.com" which loads "http://mycooldata.com/data" in an iframe.

If i do something like request.get_absolute_uri, it will return "http://mycooldata.com/data" (the url that the iframe is) when i want it to return parent url of "http://mycoolsite.com" instead.

Any ideas on how to get that to happen?

Using python 3.6 and django 1.11.

Thanks,
jAC

Comment: In general Django has no idea about your browser layout. You should use client side (i.e. Javascript) logic to check that condition.

Comment: var url = (window.location != window.parent.location)
            ? document.referrer
            : document.location.href;